# DISQUS: Is it possible to get a particular user's posts in a given forum?

Tags: disqus

I am running a web site, whose community is powered by Disqus. I would like to create user profile pages, where the page would display the particular user's most recent activity, but only for my particular site (forum, in Disqus' terminology).

I ran through the entire API documentation, but I could not find a way that would allow me to filter by both user, and forum. I would be able to grab either the entire list of posts for a given forum, or the one from a particular user.

In every API call, there is a mysterious query parameter, where I tried to plug a series of filters, but none of them worked.

Is there something that I could be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that obvious, but you can use the `query` param as a filter for users. Try something like this:

`https://disqus.com/api/3.0/forums/listPosts.json?forum={SHORTNAME}&query=user:{USERNAME}&api_key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Comment: Worked, thanks! So, that was the trick. I'd tried user.username:{USERNAME}

Comment: This seems to require that I'm the admin of the forum "`{SHORTNAME}`"?

Comment: I get: "Must have moderator permission on forum to use 'query' param". Is there a way to get my own posts?